# How to get Jquery RSS and Jcarousel to work with each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

Hi I am trying to create a simple RSS feed reader/widget.  Essentially it needs to load the data from the RSS into `<li>` elements then use jCarousel to allow them to scroll horizontally.

Both pieces work great.  However, they will not work together.  I am pretty sure what is happening is the RSS creates the UL/LI elements but are not available when jcarousel loads.  Therefore jcarousel is trying to scroll elements that don't exist.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated as I've sank too much time into it already.

Here are some working examples of what I'm doing.  Both RSS and Carousel:
http://jsfiddle.net/LuJ7M/9/

Also posting code here as well:

HTML

```
<!-- Example of carousel and rss not working together -->
<div>
  <a class="jcarousel-prev" href="#">Prev</a>
  <a class="jcarousel-next" href="#">Next</a>

  <div id="rss-feed" class="jcarousel"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
  $("#rss-feed").rss("http://www.e-ci.com/events/rss.xml", {
     limit: 5,
     layoutTemplate: '<ul id="events">{entries}</ul>',
     entryTemplate: '<li><div class="title"><a href="{url}">{title}</a></div><div class="description">{shortBodyPlain}[{author}@{date}]</div></li>'
  }).show();

  $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();

  $('.jcarousel-prev').click(function () {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '-=1');
  });

  $('.jcarousel-next').click(function () {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '+=1');
  });

});
```

Comment: To add to my question - perhaps I need to know how to load up jcarousel only after the rss ul elements have been loaded.  So some sort of check to make sure they're in place on the page before loading jcarousel.  If they are not present then don't load.

Comment: Also - here are links to the tools I'm using:

jCarousel: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/usage.html
jQueryRSS: https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss